# Kubernetes: Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "kube-verify" not found

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cluster-computing

<s>I set up a Kubernetes cluster in my private network and managed to deploy a test pods:</s>

now I want to expose an external ip for the service:

but when I run:

```
kubectl get deployments kube-verify
```

i get:

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "kube-verify" not found
```

**EDIT**
Ok I try a new approach:
i have made a namespace called: verify-cluster

My deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: verify-cluster
  namespace: verify-cluster
  labels:
    app: verify-cluster
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: verify-cluster
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: verify-cluster
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.18.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and service.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: verify-cluster
  namespace: verify-cluster
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: verify-cluster
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30007
```

then I run:

```
kubectl create -f deployment.yaml
kubectl create -f service.yaml
```

than checking

```
kubectl get all -n verify-cluster
```

but than I want to check deployment with:

```
kubectl get all -n verify-cluster
```

and get:

```
Error from server (NotFound): deployments.apps "verify-cluster" not found
```

hope that's better for reproduction ?

**EDIT 2**
when I deploy it to default namespace it runs directly so the issue must be something in the namespace

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  What is the image that you've attached to the question?

Comment: What is your kubernetes version? `kubectl version`

Comment: Version is 1.19.2

Comment: First check the cluster version using kubectl version which will provide the client and server version! Then run kubectl get pods -n verify-cluster.

Comment: Is 1.19.2 the client version or the server?

Comment: they are both the same

Comment: kubectl get pods -n verify-cluster gives me: verify-cluster-58748f68fc-jvpsr   1/1     Running   0          42m

Comment: is there a typo in question "but than I want to check deployment with: kubectl get all -n verify-cluster " . what is the command you are using to check deployment

Comment: Can you list deployments in this namespace? Post output of `kubectl auth can-i get deployment -n verify-cluster`

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you might have forgotten to create the namespace:

File my-namespace.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: <insert-namespace-name-here>
```

Then:

```
kubectl create -f ./my-namespace.yaml
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get the deployment by

```
$ kubectl get deployment
NAME                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
test-deployment   1/1     1            1           15m
```

If you have used any namespace then

```
$ kubectl get deployment -n your-namesapce
```

Then use the exact name in further commands example

```
kubectl scale deployment test-deployment --replicas=10
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replicated the use case with the config files you have provided. Everything works well at my end. Make sure that namespace is created correctly without any typo errors.
Alternatively, you can create namespace using below command:

```
kubectl create namespace <insert-namespace-name-here>
```

Refer this [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#creating-a-new-namespace) for detailed information on creating a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to apply your configuration directly to the requested namespace.

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yml -n verify-cluster
kubectl apply -f service.yml -n verify-cluster
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got the error deployment.app not found, because I used small letter instead of capital in the beginning for the Deployment. So I used:

```
kind: deployment # wrong
```

instead of

```
kind: Deployment # correct
```